# How i can display the output of a rss feed in HTML format in a TWebBrowser?

Tags: html, css, delphi, delphi-xe2, twebbrowser

I Want to show the output of a rss feed in a formatted HTML in a TWebBrowser component, if a load this feed http://code.google.com/feeds/p/v8/svnchanges/basic in a TWebbrowser, this shows the content as a XML file

[image]

but if I use IE to load the same page

[image]

I tried injecting a css to the loaded IHTMLDocument2 as is suggested in this question [CSS and TWebbrowser delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107369/css-and-twebbrowser-delphi) but i still getting the same result.

The question is, how i can load the rss feed in TWebbrowser but showing the output as HTML document like IE does?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a guess, but you might try applying the following XSL stylesheet (taken from http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/1162 and modified as suggested by cherdt in the comments below):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/atom:feed/atom:head"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/atom:feed"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="atom:feed/atom:head">
        <h3><xsl:value-of select="atom:title"/></h3>
        <xsl:if test="atom:tagline"><p><xsl:value-of select="atom:tagline"/></p></xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="atom:subtitle"><p><xsl:value-of select="atom:subtitle"/></p></xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/atom:feed">
        <h3><xsl:value-of select="atom:title"/></h3>
        <xsl:if test="atom:tagline"><p><xsl:value-of select="atom:tagline"/></p></xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="atom:subtitle"><p><xsl:value-of select="atom:subtitle"/></p></xsl:if>
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="atom:entry"/>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="atom:entry">
        <li>
            <a href="{atom:link[@rel='related']/@href}" title="{substring(atom:published, 0, 11)}"><xsl:value-of select="atom:title"/></a>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="atom:content != ''">
                    <p><xsl:value-of select="atom:content" disable-output-escaping="yes" /></p>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <p><xsl:value-of select="atom:summary" disable-output-escaping="yes" /></p>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To the feed you are receiving. To transform the document, refer to [this question's selected answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982687/how-do-i-display-xml-using-an-xslt-document-in-a-delphi-app) and then you could try to assign the resulting XML to the WebBrowser.

I am guessing that you are pointing your WebBrowser control to the feed, but using this approach you would need to download the feed using, for example, Indy (check out `TIdHTTP` and its `Get()` method), transform it, and then display in your control.

Please note that the above is just a guess, but I believe it is a good assumption. :)

Answer (score 2):

IE is applying a default style sheet and XSL transform to the RSS feed XML.  This is an IE thing rather than a standard or anything like that.

You would need to do something similar yourself by modifying the page before it is displayed.